# jQuery - which button was clicked?

Tags: jquery

I've got a page with a couple of dynamically generated buttons. When I click on one of the buttons I need to know which 'nth-child' was clicked.

```
<div>
    <button class="btn"></button>
</div>
<div>
    <button class="btn"></button>
</div>
<div>
    <button class="btn"></button>
</div>
<div>
    <button class="btn"></button>
</div>
```

So if i click on the 3rd button I need number **3** to be the outcome. This number will be used further in the application.

Comment: Attach a click event handler to the buttons, then get the index of the button which was clicked using `$(this).index()`

Comment: I provided wrong HTML code, every button is inside a div element. .index() will always give me 0 of course...

Comment: @Beeelze Then get the index of the parent element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Attach an event listener to the elements, and use the [`.index()` method](https://api.jquery.com/index/) to retrieve the index of parent element of the clicked button:

```
$('.btn').on('click', function () {
  var index = $(this).parent().index();

  // ...
});
```

As a side note, the `.index()` method is zero-based, whereas the `:nth-child()` pseudo-class's index starts at `1` (which means you will need to take that into account if you are using them together)

---

If you want the index of the parent `div` element based on siblings that contain button elements:

```
$('.btn').on('click', function () {
  var index = $('.btn').parent().index($(this).parent());

  // ...
});
```

Comment: Thanks! It is all so simple, but sometimes you just need a little help :-) And yeah, i'm using them together, so I'll keep that in mind.

Answer (score 0):

You can identify each one differently:

```
$('.btn').click(function () {
  console.log( $(this).attr('id') );
});
```

or get item index:

```
$('.btn').click(function () {
  console.log($(this).index());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to give an id to each button, just to be safe

```
$("button").click(function() {
     alert(this.id);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass `this` to the [`.index()`](https://api.jquery.com/index/#example-0) method (which will return its position within the collection `index()` was called on)

```
$('.btn').on('click', function() {
  var index = $('.btn').index(this);
});
```